# Is it possible to invoke a Servlet before showing index.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I need to do some pre-processing logic which reside in my Struts2 Action class, before showing `index.jsp` when user access my Java web application for the first time. I tried using the below snippet in `web.xml` but it failed:

**web.xml**:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>loginPage.action</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

To summarize, when user hits `http://myjavawebap.com`, first the struts2 action `loginPage` needs to be called and then the action should dispatch the default index.jsp file. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just redirect or forward to the loginPage in your index.jsp page and make index.jsp as the welcome-file.

Another solution could be to use a filter.

Comment: i thought about this redirection. But is there any other approach with out redirection? :)

Comment: You can use a filter as well. If you are trying to handle the security concerns also then its is better to use filters.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a [servlet filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) for request preprocessing.

Also Struts 2 has a similar concept called [Interceptors](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/interceptors.html) that might work for you in this case.